# An inequality concerning derivative of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ be a twice differentiable function such that $|f(x)|\le1, |f''(x)|\le1 , \forall x \in \mathbb R$ , then is it true that $|f'(x)|\le2 , \forall x \in \mathbb R$ ?

Answer (score 3):

For $x>0$ we have $f'(x)=f'(0)+\int_0^xf''(t)\,\mathrm dt\ge f'(0)-x$ and hence, again for $x>0$, 
$$\tag1 f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^xf'(t)\,\mathrm dt\ge f(0)+\int_0^x(f'(0)-t)\,\mathrm dt=f(0)+xf'(0)-\frac12x^2.$$
Assume $f'(0)>2$. Then $(1)$ implies $f(2)-f(0)\ge 2f'(0)-2>2$, contradiction.
By translation and/or reflection we obtain the same contradiction whenever there is $x$ with $|f(x)|>2$.

---

*Remark:* One can easily (how?) obtain a stronger bound for $f'$, namely $|f'(x)|\le \sqrt 2$. This improved bound is sharp, as is witnessed by
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac12x(\sqrt8-x)&\text{if $\lfloor\frac x{\sqrt 8}\rfloor$ is even}\\
\frac12x(\sqrt8+x)&\text{if $\lfloor\frac x{\sqrt 8}\rfloor$ is odd}\\\end{cases}$$
which merely has some discrete fromblems with its second derivative.